# does bootstrap interfere with other JavaScript? Like even set cookie();?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I had this working nicely, then I went and applied bootstrap to it. Now it doesn't.

This is my admin page for a little blog project of mine, where I am learning PHP from the ground up. This originally was microNews from phptoys. I made a lot of changes, and yes, the code could be way neater. (I was thinking of making a "functions" page, but that is for later)

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE['submitdate'])) {
$submitDate=$_COOKIE['submitdate'];
}
else {
$submitDate= date('Y-m-d');

}




if (isset($_COOKIE['newstitle'])) {
$newsTitle=$_COOKIE['newstitle'];
} else {
$newsTitle="News Title";

 }


 //Set no caching
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
 header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
 header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
 header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
 header("Pragma: no-cache");




 //create or edit file, protect this page from invalid users

 if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 require_once('protector.php'); 

  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">              
 <html>
 <head>
 //bootstrap stuff

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head      content must come *after* these tags -->  <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


     <title>Basic Boring Blog</title>
    <link href="style/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce.js">                </script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       tinyMCE.init({
      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
      theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",

    });
</script>



 <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

 //delete that damn cookie

 function click_agree()
 {
 document.cookie = 'newstitle = $newsTitle  ; expires =  2 Aug 1970 20:47:11 UTC;  path=/';
 document.cookie = 'submitdate = $submitDate ; expires = 2 Aug 1970 20:47:11 UTC;  path=/';


 }
 </script> 



 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">   </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">  </script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body >

//testing to see what the code knows

//since bootstrap additions, this only outputs "News Title"

<?php echo $newsTitle;?>


</br>

// this outputs nothing

<?php echo $_COOKIE['newstitle'];?>




 <?php 
  $filename = $submitDate.$newsTitle;
  ?>

   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
   <script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <div id="main2">
  <?php include 'nav.php';
  ?></div>





 <div id="main">





<?php

 //look into the specific file and see what the heck is there


$newsData = file("news/news/".$filename.".txt");


   $newsTitle  = $newsData[0];
     $submitDate = $newsData[1];    
     unset ($newsData['0']);
     unset ($newsData['1']);

     $newsContent = "";
     foreach ($newsData as $value) {
           $newsContent .= $value;
     }




      ?>
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="well">
     <div class="center-block">
     <div class="form-group">
    <form action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>'   method='post' >
    <label>News Title</label>
    <br/>
    <input type='text' name='title' size='40' value="<?php echo $newsTitle;?>"/> 
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <label>Write your thoughts here</label>
    <br/>
    <textarea  name='newstext' rows='15' cols='67'  /><?php echo   $newsContent;?></textarea><br/>
    <div class="pull-right"><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save' onClick='click_agree()' /></div>


 <br/>
  <br/>
   <br/>

 </form> </div></div>



 </div></div>
  </div></div>
<?php include 'footer.php';
 ?> 
 </body>   

 <?php } else {



  //make sure that variables are declared and then post this thing already

  $newsTitle   = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : 'Untitled';
  if (isset($_COOKIE['submitdate'])) {
   $submitDate=$_COOKIE['submitdate'];
   } else {
   $submitDate= date('Y-m-d');
   $newsContent = isset($_POST['newstext']) ? $_POST['newstext'] : 'No content';

  $filename = $submitDate.$newsTitle;
  $f = fopen('news/news/'.$filename.".txt","w+"); 

 //the page that will be made
  $written ="

  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head     content must come *after* these tags -->
   <link href='style/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
   <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <title>Basic Boring Blog</title>
        <link href='http://pluckzilla.byethost32.com/microblog/microNews/style/bootstrap.css'   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />


      <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
      function click_agree()
 {
document.cookie = 'newstitle = $newsTitle; expires = 2 Aug 2017 20:47:11 UTC;  path=/';
 document.cookie = 'submitdate = $submitDate; expires = 2 Aug 2017 20:47:11 UTC;  path=/';

 window.location.href =    'http://www.pluckzilla.com/microblog/microNews/admin.php';
  }
</script> 






  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js'>  </script>
  <script src='https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js'></script>
 <![endif]-->


 </head>

 <body >



   <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script   src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'>    </script>
   <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>


 <div id=\"main2\">

 <?php include 'nav.php';
 ?> 
  </div>






 <div>
 <div id='main' class='pull-right'>

 <span='title'><h1>$newsTitle</h1></span>
 <span='date'>$submitDate</span>
  <span><p>$newsContent</p></span>

  <button name='edit' onClick='click_agree()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' aria-hidden='true'></span></button></div>
```

I had the new page this admin page creates load up 2 cookies using a JavaScript (), then redirect back to the admin page. The cookies would then be used to call up the aforementioned created page using php, and would load it onto the form, for editing. Finally, the form button would then erase the cookies.

Basically, I enabled the admin page to edit pages, rather than just creating them.

Then I added bootstrap, because, well, it's awesome. Now my admin page doesn't work.

I had to have done something wrong, but I look at the code and everything looks much the same as before, except for the bootstrap bits. I removed some of the bootstrap, mostly from the form since it is key for this to work, but it still doesn't work.

...on top of this, this code for the admin page on my "live" server has to be slightly different on the form above than the one THAT! WORKS! JUST! FINE! on my localhost.(Windows 7 based, wamp). I copied the code that WAS working on the server, and was careful not change it as I added the bootstrap bits. I could not test it locally, and alas, I was not successful.

Comment: Do you still have a copy of the code from beforehand that works?

Comment: unfortunately no. I stupidly made assumptions.

Comment: Yeesh, that's why you should use version control. Sorry to hear that happened to you. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your time. i'm going to try and rebuild what i lost

Comment: have you checked browser console for error and please add the bootstrap.min.js above all the js files, which you have added.........because sometimes it overrides the Jquery methods

Comment: I just finished rebuilding. I still have no idea what is wrong with the above code, but the new code is working fine....and i have eyestrain. I did remove the facebook and discus plug-ins i had coded on the created page, so maybe it wasn't bootstrap that caused the problems. i could have missed a dang ";" or "}" somewhere.

Comment: Anyhow, i will now be saving several versions of coding for my projects. What a "D'oh!"

Comment: I usee notepad++ for coding, no errors were raised.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is

> No, CSS does not interfere with JavaScript.

JavaScript, by nature, is able to change things in your page, including CSS and sometimes might make it seem like CSS is not working, when it actually does. (Unless you have a syntax error, CSS always works and is quite predictable. If it doesn't apply on an element it means it's overridden by another CSS rule or inline styling you are not aware of). A very simple way to check if your project works (or not) with Bootstrap's CSS loaded is to add this line in your page's `head` tag (try it on your local machine first) and remove all other Bootstrap references:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

However, Bootstrap comes with JavaScript too. And that might interfere with other JavaScript in your page, although, unless you're using different versions of Bootstrap in different plugins/widgets of your page, it usually doesn't. From what I see in the code you posted above, you are using both CSS and Javascript from Bootstrap. So I guess your question should be reformulated.

Can you please explain in detail what exactly is not working on your remote server and was working on your local machine? This might have nothing to do with JavaScript. It is probably related to `Apache` or `php` service differences between the two machines.

Comment: I have made massive changes since this problem arose. Among them, dumping tinyMCE from the project. Yes, i was aware that bootstrap has a jquery component, and a google search didnt turn up any known issues. Thus my question above. I updated the jquery to a newer version, which seemd to help. That, and rebuilding the code once again from the original. I am going to chalk this up as "i had massive typos", rather than it being a truly bootstrap issue.

Comment: Javascript is a workaround for non web standard browsers, like internet explorer, in regards to its role in css. Or so i think. I have much to learn.